# How to bind datagrid from one window with textboxes in other window?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I'm trying to create one main window with Airports data, and one seperate window for Editing data. Currently, I'm only can bind datagrid and textboxes in the same window, but how to bind them in EditWindow?

AirportsWindow (main window):

```
public partial class AirportsWindow : Window
    {

        public AirportsWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            using (SQLiteConnection dataConnection = new SQLiteConnection()) 
            {
                try
                {
                    dataConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=database.db;Version=3;";
                    dataConnection.Open();
                    SQLiteCommand dataCommand = new SQLiteCommand();
                    dataCommand.Connection = dataConnection;


                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Грешка при повезивању с базом " + e.Message);

                }
            }

            string database_connection = "Data Source=database.db;Version=3;";
            string query = String.Format("SELECT * FROM airports WHERE active = '1'");

            SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(database_connection);
            connection.Open();

            SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(query, connection);
            SQLiteDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(command);

            DataTable data = new DataTable();           
            dataAdapter.Fill(data);
            dgAirports.DataContext = data;

        }
```

And here is EditWindow:

```
<Grid x:Name="FormGrid" DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=Dgrid}">

        <Label x:Name="lblAirportId" Content="ИД" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,12,0,0"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtAirportId" Text="{Binding ElementName=dgAirports, Path=SelectedValue.id}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="125" Margin="48,13,0,0"/>

        <Label x:Name="lblAirportName" Content="Назив" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,38,0,0"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtAirportName" Text="{Binding ElementName=dgAirports, Path=SelectedValue.airportName}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="125" Margin="48,41,0,0"/>

        <Label x:Name="lblAirportCity" Content="Град" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="2,69,0,0"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtAirportCity" Text="{Binding ElementName=dgAirports, Path=SelectedValue.airportCity}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="125" Margin="48,72,0,0"/>


        <Button x:Name="btnEdit" Content="Додај" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,100,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="btnEdit_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnCancel" Content="Одустани" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="98,100,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="btnCancel_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Also here is how I done and binded in the AirportsWindow (main window)

```
<Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="dgAirports" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="100" Width="272" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="false" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Шифра" Binding="{Binding Path = id}" Width="*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Назив" Binding="{Binding Path = airportName}"  Width="*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Град" Binding="{Binding Path = airportCity}" Width="*"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>

        <Label x:Name="lblAirportId" Content="ИД" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="123,115,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtAirportId" Text="{Binding ElementName=dgAirports, Path=SelectedValue.id}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="157,115,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="125"/>

        <Label x:Name="lblAirportName" Content="Назив" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="109,142,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtAirportName" Text="{Binding ElementName=dgAirports, Path=SelectedValue.airportName}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="157,143,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="125"/>

        <Label x:Name="lblAirportCity" Content="Град" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="115,168,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtAirportCity" Text="{Binding ElementName=dgAirports, Path=SelectedValue.airportCity}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="157,171,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="125"/>

        <Button x:Name="btnAdd" Content="Додај" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,115,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="btnAdd_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnEdit" Content="Измени" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,142,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="btnEdit_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnDelete" Content="Избриши" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,170,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="btnDelete_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ICommand or RelayCommand implemented in main window data context and set selected item as data context of edit window.
You can pass it as parameter through edit window constructor.

Problem in current implementation is that you are accessing element by name (Dgrid) from separate xaml.

My suggestion is to try to implement your application using MVVM pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the MVVM pattern, or at least parts of the idea behind.

Model:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string MyProperties { get; set; }
}
```

MainWindow:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public MyModel Model { get; set; }

    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Only time creating an instance of MyModel
        Model = new MyModel();
        Model.MyProperties = string.Empty;

        // Pass reference of MyModel to other Windows (or even better ViewModels)
        Window2 wnd = new Window2(Model);

        wnd.Show();


        MessageBox.Show(Model.MyProperties);
        // Output: "This is an example."
    }
}
```

Child window:

```
public partial class Window2 : Window
{
    // Don't create another instance, just pass the existing instance reference
    public MyModel Model { get; set; }

    public Window2(MyModel model)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Model = model;

        // Modifying Properties from here will also update in Window1
        Model.MyProperties = "This is an example.";
    }
}
```